# netmiko: can't execute commands from list

Tags: python, python-3.x, netmiko

I've no issue executing Cisco command via string `cmd = 'show version | include IOS'`

```
from netmiko import ConnectHandler

cisco_device = {
    'device_type': 'cisco_ios',
    'ip': 'Router1',
    'username': 'u',
    'password': 'p'
}

# string OK
cmd = 'show version | include IOS'
print(type(cmd))

net_connect = ConnectHandler(**cisco_device)
output = net_connect.send_command(cmd)
print(output)
```

Output

```
user@linux:~$ python script-str.py 
<class 'str'>
Cisco IOS Software, 3700 Software (C3725-ADVENTERPRISEK9-M), Version 12.4(15)T7, RELEASE SOFTWARE (fc3)
user@linux:~$
```

However, when I changed it to list, it doesn't work.

```
from netmiko import ConnectHandler

cisco_device = {
    'device_type': 'cisco_ios',
    'ip': 'Router1',
    'username': 'u',
    'password': 'p'
}

# list problem
cmd = ['show version | include IOS']
print(type(cmd))

net_connect = ConnectHandler(**cisco_device)
output = net_connect.send_command(cmd)
print(output)
```

Output

```
user@linux:~$ python script-list.py
<class 'list'>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "script-list.py", line 14, in <module>
    output = net_connect.send_command(cmd)
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/netmiko/utilities.py", line 347, in wrapper_decorator
    return func(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/netmiko/base_connection.py", line 1378, in send_command
    command_string = self.normalize_cmd(command_string)
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/netmiko/base_connection.py", line 1532, in normalize_cmd
    command = command.rstrip()
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'rstrip'
user@linux:~$
```

What's wrong with the `list` on second code and how to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your script `net_connect.send_command(cmd)` accepts string as parameter and you are passing list to it.

In your second example try sending string value from list `cmd[0]` which is a string.

```
from netmiko import ConnectHandler

cisco_device = {
    'device_type': 'cisco_ios',
    'ip': 'Router1',
    'username': 'u',
    'password': 'p'
}

# list problem
cmd = ['show version | include IOS']
print(type(cmd))

net_connect = ConnectHandler(**cisco_device)
output = net_connect.send_command(cmd[0])
print(output)
```

refer: https://github.com/ktbyers/netmiko/issues/167

Comment: It works! What I'm trying to do is to send multiple commands ... I thought `list` was able to do that. Do you have any idea how to do this?

Comment: You have to use for loop to iterate over list with multiple commands. check https://github.com/ktbyers/netmiko/issues/167#issuecomment-174067037

Comment: Got it, but I'm having a problem to get the output in new line. Could you please take at look? Thanks

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61222029/netmiko-how-to-sends-get-command-output-in-a-new-line