# netmiko: How to sends get command output in a new line

Tags: python, python-3.x, netmiko

This is the script

```
from netmiko import ConnectHandler

cisco_device = {
    'device_type': 'cisco_ios',
    'ip': 'Router1',
    'username': 'u',
    'password': 'p'
}

net_connect = ConnectHandler(**cisco_device)

cmd = ['show clock', 'show version | include IOS']
output = ''
for command in cmd:
    output += net_connect.send_command(command)

print(output)
```

Output

As you can see, the output is displayed in a single line

```
user@linux:~$ python script.py 

*00:22:10.927 UTC Fri Mar 1 2002Cisco IOS Software, 3700 Software (C3725-ADVENTERPRISEK9-M), Version 12.4(15)T7, RELEASE SOFTWARE (fc3)
user@linux:~$
```

Desired Output

I would like to separate each output in a new line

```
*00:23:31.943 UTC Fri Mar 1 2002
Cisco IOS Software, 3700 Software (C3725-ADVENTERPRISEK9-M), Version 12.4(15)T7, RELEASE
```

Comment: You could try using the `send_config_set()` method, which accepts a list of commands to be send to the device.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
output = []
for command in cmd:
    output.append(net_connect.send_command(command))
    print(output[-1])
```

Comment: Thanks @Teejay. It works. Could you please take a look at this? Somehow I can't execute `sh run` in netmiko

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61222731/netmiko-cant-execute-sh-run-i-host

Answer (score 0):

Other way would be appending newline `"\n"` on each line

```
output = ''
for command in cmd:
    output += net_connect.send_command(command) + "\n"

print(output)
```