# netmiko can't execute 'sh run | i host'

Tags: python, python-3.x, netmiko

I notice that my netmiko code can't run `sh run | i host` which is a legitimate Cisco command.

When I replace `sh run` with other command such as `sh clo`, or `show ip interface brief`, it works perfectly.

```
from netmiko import ConnectHandler

R1 = {
    'device_type': 'cisco_ios',
    'ip': 'Router1',
    'username': 'u',
    'password': 'p'
}

R2 = {
    'device_type': 'cisco_ios',
    'ip': 'Router2',
    'username': 'u',
    'password': 'p'
}

all_devices = [R1, R2]

for device in all_devices:
    connect = ConnectHandler(**device)
    output = connect.send_command('sh run | i host')
    print(output)
```

Output

```
user@linux:~$ python3 script.py 
^
% Invalid input detected at '^' marker.

^
% Invalid input detected at '^' marker.

user@linux:~$
```

Desired Output

```
hostname Router1
hostname Router2
```

Any idea why this code behave this way?

Answer (score 0):

`sh run` is short for `show running-config`; this is a privileged-mode command (requires `enable` first) and you're trying to issue it in unprivileged mode.

Comment: To access the privilege mode in Netmiko you'll need to execute `connect.enable()`.  
The privilege mode will be required anytime the router has en `enable secret` or `enable password` commands defined.